# Default Focus Color of BlackBerry Fields

Tags: blackberry, focus, field

Does anyone know what is the constant code of default focus color of BlackBerry Fields(blueish)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the gradient highlighting, the colors I found are `0x00207CFE` for the top and `0x00074CAC` for the bottom.

Comment: your color seems to similar to default colors, but i am gonna use 0x00088EEF. It is better i think.